# Form value display in angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created a simple form using angular js. when the submit button is clicked, i want the details entered to be displayed under it also want the details to be saved in console in JSON format.

View code:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="person_info">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Person info</title>
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="controller_class2.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="info">
  Name: <input type="text" ng-model="person.name"> </br></br>
  First Name : <input type="text" ng-model="person.firstname"></br></br>
  Phone Number : <input type="text" ng-model="person.number"></br></br>
  Email : <input type="email" ng-model="person.email"></br></br>
  Address : <input type="text" ng-model="person.address"></br></br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit" ng-click="test()">

  <p>{{person.name}}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller code :

```
var person_info = angular.module('person_info', []);
person_info.controller('info', function($scope) {   
$scope.test = function(){
$scope.person = person;
console.log($scope.person);
}
});
```

Something seems to be wrong. i am not getting the proper output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LFgwb/) what you mean?

```
.controller('info', function($scope) {
$scope.test = function () {
    $scope.newPerson = $scope.person;
    console.log($scope.newPerson);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A model binding automatically binds to a scope property.

The line:

```
$scope.person = person;
```

in your method overrides the correct person with an undefined object. The method will work if you remove this line.

```
$scope.test = function(){
  console.log($scope.person);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/YWfSF/4/ 
You have overrode `$scope.person = person; //person is undefined`